# How to make fixed grid view with image in column in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gridview, jsx, native-base

Hello I'm trying to create fixed (responsive) grid view with 3 cols in each row.In each column there will be an image and by clicking on that it will navigate to corresponding page.I'm using `native-base ui kit`.I found an easy way of creating grid view in their documentation.But the problem is when I tried to give Image within column the full width of image is not loading also when I take the out in different phones the grid view is not responsive.The reason is that I've set height and width property to `col` component of `Grid`.But if i don't set a height then nothing will render I will get a blank page.Also I haven't set `height` to Image because I want to render the full width of Image.How do I achieve that ? I'm expecting exactly like this

[image]

But what I'm getting is  this

[image]

Following is my code

**updated**

```
           <Col size={33.33}>
           <TouchableOpacity onPress ={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Header")}>
           <Image source={require('../../imgs/eco.jpg')} style={styl.image} />

           </TouchableOpacity>
              </Col>
           <Col size={33.33}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress ={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Footer")}>

             <Image source={require('../../imgs/file.jpg')} style={styl.image} />


             </TouchableOpacity>
           </Col>
           <Col size={33.33}>
           <TouchableOpacity onPress ={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("NHBadge") }>

             <Image source={require('../../imgs/economy.jpg')} style={styl.image} />


             </TouchableOpacity>
           </Col>

         </Row>
         </Grid>
```

style

```
col:{
     flex:1,
     margin:5,
     width:120,
     height:200
    },
    col2:{
      flex:1,
      padding:90,
      backgroundColor:"#ddd",
      alignItems:'center',
      margin:5,
      height:200,
      width:120,

     },
image:{
      flex:1,
      position: 'absolute',
       justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',


},
 textStyle:{
   color:'white',
    fontSize:15,
    fontWeight:'bold',
    alignSelf:'center'
   },
   viewStyle:{
     position: 'absolute',
      justifyContent: 'center',
       alignItems: 'center',
       top: 0,
        left: 0,
         right: 0,
          bottom: 0
   },
```

The full width of image is not loading also how do I make the 3 cols fit in screen without adding `height` and `width` properties?Please help me to figure out the mistake in my code.Any help would be really appreciable.Thank you

Comment: You can get `screenWidth` and by performing some calculations you can make it work for only 3 elements

Comment: I've edited my code please check.

Comment: Now I'm getting this https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYDIA.png.It will fit within screen but size is too small.What to do?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
resizeMode: 'contain',
```

in your image style for full width